# Siri doesn't always work without "start", "end", "pause", "resume", "cancel" and "workout" keyword for workout domain

Tags: ios, swift, siri

Actually, I am using Siri in my app with workout domain. What I see, Siri doesn't always work without "start", "end", "pause", "resume", "cancel" and "workout" keyword for workout domain.

For example:- If I give a command like `"Start my 1-mile workout with myapp"` it works fine.

But If I give a command like `"Log my 1-mile workout with myapp"` it sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is can be implemented using [INVocabulary class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/invocabulary). After Siri authorization, place the following code snippet, for a bunch of uncommon words are "log" (your example), "record my run", "remember my run". Thus, your ViewController might start to look like:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()

         INPreferences.requestSiriAuthorization { (status) in

        }

        INVocabulary.shared().setVocabularyStrings(["log","record my run", "remember my run"], of: .workoutActivityName)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @kubo. But "log", "record my run","remember my run". These are not workout names so I think it would not be a good practice to keep these all as workout name.